# how to get the user list those who are access my facebook application through my iphone apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

i am creating an iphone apps which need to use facebook login details to enter into the apps as Groupon iphone apps. 
In Groupon, they are using FBConnect to access their facebook application, based on the login success they are allowing me to access their deals.

I had used FBConnect package to post some message to user's wall using my own facebook application API. But not clear as how to use facebook login details to enter into my apps as in groupon.

my questions as follow,

Is there any way to access the user details who are used registered to access my iphone apps which using my facebook application API?

Advanced Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the readme file shown beneath the source directories at http://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk

It sounds like you're talking about two things.

First, you want your app to get extended permission from your user so you can access their specific information.

Second, you want to query Facebook for that information once you have permission.  You can do that by making specific Facebook API calls once you have permission.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I have read facebook documents and understand the single signon process and their API to retrive user details those who gave extended permission to our apps. thanks!